# laravel policy authorize always false

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to allow users editing their own review in Laravel 5.5

*AuthServiceProvider.php*

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use App\Model\Review;
use App\Policies\ReviewPolicy;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        Review::class => ReviewPolicy::class,
    ];
```

*ReviewPolicy.php*

```
public function update(User $user, Review $review)
{
    return $user->id == $review->user_id;
}
```

*ReviewController.php*

```
public function update(Request $request, Review $review ,int $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'content' => 'required|min:250',
        'score' => 'numeric|min:0|max:10',
    ]);

    $this->authorize('update', $review);

    $reviewsSave = Review::find($id);
    $reviewsSave->content = $request->input('content');
    $reviewsSave->score = $request->input('score');
    $reviewsSave->save();

    return redirect(url()->current());

}
```

I keep getting

*Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ AccessDeniedHttpException
This action is unauthorized.*

When in fact it should be authorized

I am probably missing something but I can't find what.

Comment: Please put `dd(auth()->id(), $review);` before the `authorize` line and show the results.

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/ecab6bf1f331d67fce792c16fa257485.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is model binding doesn't work because `$review` is empty. To make it work the route should look like this:

```
Route::get('review/update/{review}/{id}', 'ReviewController@update');
```

Or, you could fetch the review manually:

```
public function update(Request $request, Review $review ,int $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'content' => 'required|min:250',
        'score' => 'numeric|min:0|max:10',
    ]);

    $reviewsSave = Review::find($id);

    $this->authorize('update', $reviewsSave);

    $reviewsSave->content = $request->input('content');
    $reviewsSave->score = $request->input('score');
    $reviewsSave->save();

    return redirect(url()->current());
}
```